# How can I run Dropbox on Mac OS X Mountain Lion without logging in?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion, dropbox

I'm using Dropbox to sync files to my web site, which is running on Mac OS X Mountain Lion.  Problem is, if I am not logged in, Dropbox isn't running and as a result any changes I make to my web site on another computer linked to Dropbox, the web site does not update.

I have tried to solve the problem by making Dropbox run as a daemon at startup.  I created a launchd entry in /Library/LaunchDaemons using the UserName key to run Dropbox as myself, and it launches, but nothing updates.  When I redirect the output of the Dropbox executable to a file, I see the following error, although it isn't obvious to me that it is fatal, and I still see Dropbox in the process list.

```
/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-ol_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
2013-09-15 17:42:20.592 Dropbox[267:707] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:

(
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x5636c30 H:[_NSAlertContentView:0x56319e0(<=0)]>,
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x5636b70 H:[_NSAlertContentView:0x56319e0(>=420)]>
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x5636c30 H:[_NSAlertContentView:0x56319e0(<=0)]>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
2013-09-15 17:42:20.593 Dropbox[267:707] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:

(
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x5637240 V:[_NSAlertContentView:0x56319e0(<=0)]>,
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x5637180 V:[_NSAlertContentView:0x56319e0(>=131)]>
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x5637240 V:[_NSAlertContentView:0x56319e0(<=0)]>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
2013-09-15 17:42:20.612 Dropbox[267:707] Error (1000) creating CGSWindow on line 259
2013-09-15 17:42:20.614 Dropbox[267:707] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x98598e8b __raiseError + 219
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x987e152e objc_exception_throw + 230
2   CoreFoundation                      0x98598d21 -[NSException raise] + 17
3   _objc.so                            0x02b30b2f PyObjCErr_ToObjCWithGILState + 63
4   _objc.so                            0x02b11501 PyObjCFFI_BuildResult + 4673
5   _objc.so                            0x02b0254f ffi_closure_SYSV_inner + 127
6   _objc.so                            0x02b02352 ffi_closure_SYSV + 34
7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x987ee5d3 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
8   Foundation                          0x90d9d326 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 395
9   CoreFoundation                      0x9846f04f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
10  CoreFoundation                      0x9846ea79 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 233
11  CoreFoundation                      0x98494826 __CFRunLoopRun + 934
12  CoreFoundation                      0x9849401a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 378
13  CoreFoundation                      0x98493e8b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
14  HIToolbox                           0x9107af5a RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 242
15  HIToolbox                           0x9107acc9 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 374
16  HIToolbox                           0x9107ab44 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 88
17  AppKit                              0x9907693a _DPSNextEvent + 724
18  AppKit                              0x9907616c -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 119
19  AppKit                              0x9906c5cc -[NSApplication run] + 855
20  _objc.so                            0x02b022ad ffi_call_SYSV + 29
21  _objc.so                            0x02b025c9 ffi_call + 89
22  _objc.so                            0x02b1b2e9 PyObjCFFI_Caller + 2809
23  _objc.so                            0x02b4006a PyObjCSelector_GetClass + 698
24  Python                              0x02209918 PyObject_Call + 88
25  Python                              0x022be2cf PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 5663
26  Python                              0x022c4571 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2081
27  Python                              0x022c20d3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 21539
28  Python                              0x022c4571 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2081
29  Python                              0x022c20d3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 21539
30  Python                              0x022c4571 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2081
31  Python                              0x0223b3d2 PyClassMethod_New + 1138
32  Python                              0x02209918 PyObject_Call + 88
33  Python                              0x022bea8c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 7644
34  Python                              0x022c4571 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2081
35  Python                              0x022c20d3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 21539
36  Python                              0x022c2fb2 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 25346
37  Python                              0x022c2fb2 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 25346
38  Python                              0x022c2fb2 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 25346
39  Python                              0x022c4571 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2081
40  Python                              0x022c46f7 PyEval_EvalCode + 87
41  Python                              0x022e8fa5 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 789
42  Python                              0x022e90f8 PyRun_SimpleFile + 40
43  Dropbox                             0x000067f1 start + 17777
44  Dropbox                             0x00006f89 main + 1481
45  Dropbox                             0x00002382 start + 258
46  Dropbox                             0x000022a9 start + 41
```

`

Comment: Is there some reason you don't create a separate user just for this purpose and leave that account logged in?

Comment: this machine is shared with other users and the machine sometimes gets restarted when i am not around, in which case the other account wouldn't get logged on (and it would be annoying to the other users as well as a security hole to have it automatically log that user on every boot)

Comment: and by security hole that includes the 2 year old coming along and accidentally messing everything up because it automatically logged the "web" account on.

Comment: You can't sync with Dropbox unless you log into your account I am not sure I fully understand the question

Comment: I mean log in from the GUI.  I don't understand why the GUI would be necessary to run the Dropbox daemon to sync files, the GUI is a totally unrelated layer.

Answer (score 0):

The "**Error (1000) creating CGSWindow on line 259**" shows that the internal Python app needs some form of graphical interface needed (perhaps the flash screen or the menu pop-up). By default, the LaunchAgents/Daemons don't have graphical access, it might not even be activated yet.

From the `launchctl` man page:

> Currently known session types include: Aqua, LoginWindow, Background,
>   StandardIO and System.

In launchd plist file, try adding the `LimitLoadToSessionType` requirement of "Aqua" and "LoginWindow" session type.

```
<key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
  <array>
    <string>LoginWindow</string>
    <string>Aqua</string>
  </array>
```

Beware, that an app will probably be quit and restarted when logging in. From the [Apple Daemon technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html):

> If you set LimitLoadToSessionType to an array, be aware that each
>   instance of your agent runs independently. For example, if you set up
>   your agent to run in LoginWindow and Aqua, the system will first run
>   an instance of your agent in the loginwindow context. When a user logs
>   in, that instance will be terminated and a second instance will launch
>   in the standard GUI context.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a lot of work for something that can be accomplished with Mercurial/Git running on the target machine without logging in. With that you get the added advantage of source control.

[Automatic pull from Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2FCommonProblems.Any_way_to_.27hg_push.27_and_have_an_automatic_.27hg_update.27_on_the_remote_server.3F)

Comment: I know it's possible and done, but I would rather not keep lots of image files in version control.

Comment: I can appreciate that but as DVCS's like mercurial only store change sets, it'd mean you weren't pulling the full repo each time - only the changes. Plus it gives you the traceability and exact functionality you require from dropbox. 
Alternatively of course, could you not just FTP direct to the server?